# Different landing pages for the same domain VPS

Tags: apache, ubuntu-16.04, vps

I have a self-managed VPS server with no control panel running Ubuntu. I managed to point my domain to the server successfully. Then I installed apache2. I created an index landing page in directory:

```
var/www/gci/
```

By default system created another directory with default index landing page:

```
var/www/html/
```

Then I edited the **gci.conf** under directory:

```
/etc/apache2/sites-available/
```

to include the following lines:
ServerAdmin myemail
DocumentRoot /var/www/html
ServerName burooq.com

The whole file contents is as follows:

```js
<VirtualHost *:80>
        # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
        # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
        # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
        # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
        # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
        # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
        # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
        #ServerName www.example.com


        ServerAdmin myemail
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html
        ServerName burooq.com

        # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
        # error, crit, alert, emerg.
        # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
        # modules, e.g.
        #LogLevel info ssl:warn

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

        # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
        # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
        # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
        # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
        # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
        #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
</VirtualHost>

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

My issue is basically, when I access my domain using **http://Burooq.com**, it lands on the index page under **gci** folder. However, when I use **https://Burooq.com**, it lands on the index page under **html** folder. How is that possible and how would I point both request to one landing page.

Comment: Please add full content of gci.conf and www.conf without safe sensitive data

Comment: @AdamP full content added

Comment: This is only for HTTP, not contains HTTPS (SSL) related configuration. Which files are linked in `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/` directory?